# Bash tuple on json string

Tags: json, linux, bash

I have a specific problem. I make email variable in bash script like:

```
tDestinationEmail=email@email.com
```

and if I enter an email after the sign = my json should look like this:

```
{"ToAddresses": ["email@email.com"]}
```

I try to do it with

```
 tDestinationEmailJSON='{"ToAddresses": ["$tDestinationEmail"]}'
```

but on the output i getting

```
 {"ToAddresses": ["$tDestinationEmail"]}
```

Maybe whom know solution how i can do it ? Please suggest!

Comment: try:  `tDestinationEmailJSON='{"ToAddresses": ['"$tDestinationEmail"']}'`

Comment: the output is : {"ToAddresses": [Zorro55@gmail.com]} , but i need  {"ToAddresses": ["Zorro55@gmail.com"]}

Comment: `tDestinationEmailJSON='{"ToAddresses": ['"\"$tDestinationEmail\""']}'`

Comment: Works!!! @Ardit , add Answer  i will like you!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From man page of `bash`:

"Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes."

So when you call `$tDestinationEmail` will be treated as string and will not call the value of the variable.

Using double quotes:

`tDestinationEmailJSON='{"ToAddresses": ['"\"$tDestinationEmail\""']}'`

Comment: In general, you shouldn't attempt to create JSON values with interpolation like this. It won't work if `$tDestinationEmail` contained a character that wasn't valid for a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

**jq** is the right tool for *JSON* data manipulation:

```
tDestinationEmail="email@email.com"

jq -nc --arg email "$tDestinationEmail" '{ToAddresses: [$email]}'
```

The output:

```
{"ToAddresses":["email@email.com"]}
```

Comment: from where are '{ToAddresses: [$email]}'  this $email?

Comment: @Andrej, it's the argument `--arg email` passed in `jq` expression

Comment: Don't confuse `$email` in the single-quoted argument to `jq` with a shell parameter expansion; it looks similar, but is meant to be interpreted by `jq` itself.